# Skip data when reading a text file

Tags: c#, io, file-read

i have a text file ... which storing data like..

> E:0
>
> S:0
>
> R:0
>
> G:0
>
> E:1
>
> S:1
>
> R:1
>
> G:1

and so on till 50. I can read it by

```
StramReader.ReadLine();
```

but how i can read the 1st line

> E:0

and skip to the next E: , without getting the in between things

Comment: "with out reading the in between things": Impossible. How to know when the next "E" is reached when you don't read the data?

Comment: ok let me edit that part then

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Well, if the data is of fixed length, you could read the file bytewise and skip the unwanted data using `Stream.Seek`. But the question is if you *really* want to do this...

Comment: no the data is not of fixed length

Comment: @Mr.Steak: Sure, but the question didn't sound as if the data was fixed length and the OP just confirmed that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I just said you *could* in theory if the data *is* fixed length. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this way. But this will go through each row and select the rows that contains E

```
var linesContainsE = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    .Where(line => line.Contains("E"))
    .ToList();
```

(Using namespace System.Linq and System.IO)

More info about the File.ReadAllLines from msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx

Comment: what linesContainsE will store? will it store the whole string?

Comment: @Drone linesContainsE will be a collection of the lines in files that contains E

Comment: @AlexR. How will we else know if the row contains E? We can't know this without reading the rows.

Comment: @JonasW ok so how will i get those individual strings from that?

Comment: @Drone you can pick em out for example using linesContainsE.ElementAt(index). But what do you want to do with the values?

Comment: lineContainsE will be of type IEnumerable<string>, so you can do: foreach(var line in lineContainsE) Console.WriteLine(line);

Comment: @JonasW i have to show them on textboxes. what "index" would be?

Comment: @rasmusvhansen ok it seems it may work i will try and let u know

Comment: @Jonas W, exactly. Without reading the file, we can't know. What the OP is asking is impossible based on this premise.

Comment: Just stick a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end.

Comment: @Drone - not much. Just add `.ToList()` before the `;` in Jonas' statement. Then you have a `List<string>` as the result.

Comment: @JonasW do I have to use some namespace for this bcoz i am not getting it

Comment: yeah i have that System.Linq; but still not getting it. I am not getting `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: That's in the System.IO namespace.

Comment: Here is a link to msdn that will explain this method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx

Comment: @JonasW One more thing sir.. what is the 1st "line" ?

Comment: linesContainsE.First() or linesContainsE.ElementAt(0). While you debug the application you can clearly see the result of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It would be strong recommended instead of using ReadAllLines which loads all lines in memory. What if you have a very large file, using ReadAllLines would be not efficient.

Another alternative is [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), it is deferred execution:

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Moreover, instead of using `Contains`, use `StartWith`:

```
var linesContainsE = File.ReadLines(filename)
                         .Where(line => line.StartWith("E"))
                         .ToList();
```